# ¿Cómo enviar el valor de un radioButton a Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, radiobutton, firestore

Me encuentro buscando actualmente la forma de poder enviar el valor seleccionado de un radioButton almacenado en un radioGroup hacia Firestore en Kotlin.

Me resulta con el valor de los spinner y los EditText pero no he logrado encontrar la forma de hacerlo con los radio button.

```
class ArnesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityArnesBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val db : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        binding = ActivityArnesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.btnsend.setOnClickListener {
            val checkedsinona = binding.radioGroup1.checkedRadioButtonId
            val sinona = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedsinona)
            saveFireStore(sinona)
        }
    }

    private fun saveFireStore(sinona: RadioButton) {
        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val user: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        user["Nombre"] = sinona
        db.collection("Lista_Control_Arnés")
            .add(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@ArnesActivity, "Guardado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@ArnesActivity, "Falló", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que estas realizando por favor, al menos lo que investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Disculpa, creí haberlo hecho. ya esta corregido, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes enviar el texto del botón (propiedad `text`), no el botón completo

```
user["Nombre"] = sinona.text
```

Aunque yo cambiaría la función para que acepte una `String` en vez de un `RadioButton`

```
private fun saveToFirestore(sinona: String) {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val user = mapOf("Nombre" to sinona)
    db.collection("Lista_Control_Arnés").add(user).addOnCompleteListener {
        val message = if (it.isSuccessful) "Guardado" else "Falló"
        Toast.makeText(this@ArnesActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Y luego la llamas así

```
val sinona = findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedsinona)
saveToFirestore(sinona.text.toString())
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! puede que sea algo básica quizás las pregunta pero estoy aprendiendo hace poco sobre programación.

Comment: Sí, es muy básica pero haces bien en preguntar, para eso existe este sitio. Y no hace falta que des las gracias. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)